# How to "merge" two objects of the same class

Tags: java, groovy

The code is groovy but the answer can be both, Groovy or Java. 
I have a Person class with this fields:

```
class Person(){
String name
String lasName
}
```

I have a method that returns two objects from the same class. One object with some fields and the other with the rest, in my example it would be like this:

```
person1 = "name : Jon"
person2 = "lastName : Snow"
```

What I need is to replace all the null fields of `person1` with the `person2` field if this is not null, in our example, the output would be:

```
person1.merge(person2)
person1= "name : Jon, lastName : Snow"
```

Is there any method on Java or Groovy to do something similar to this without writing all my fields(using some kind of loop)?

If there isn't any default method to use, how can I iterate through all the fields from a class?

Comment: Did you try to use reflection for your data?

Comment: The SDK does not provide such a method. You can use reflection api for doing this. But the real question is - why do you need to do it? There should always be a better approach that does not lead to such situation.

Comment: I have been told to avoid using reflection because it can affects to the performance, what do you think about this? EDIT: yes, @Prashant there are better approaches but I can't change the incoming data (I receive three different objects that I need to merge in the same class and I don't want to change my code if some field is added in the future...)

Comment: Its not really the performance, its the security since if you obfuscate your code you may get problems

Comment: Yeah, you could use reflection but it seems like a really bad idea. Just write the code by hand if you really want to do it that way. Just write a utility `T firstNonNull(T a, T b)` method and your code should look good enough.

Comment: Reflection is the best way, or you can write a program to manually generate the method for you.

Comment: could you write an answer with the reflection code to get a list with all the fields of a class??

Comment: Done, enjoy :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a quick (and presumptuous) approach that is basically the same as using reflection on the fields but instead uses:

1. Groovy's built-in [`getProperties()` method](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#getProperties()) on java.lang.Object, which provides us with a Map of its property names and values
2. Groovy's [default Map constructor](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_list_and_map_constructors), which allows use to create instances of an Object given a Map of properties.

Given these two features, you can describe each object you want to merge as a Map of their properties, strip out the `null`-valued entries, combine the Maps together (and remove the pesky 'class' entry which is readonly), and use the merged Map to construct your merged instance.

```
class Person {
    String first, last, middle
}

def p1 = new Person(first: 'bob')
def p2 = new Person(last: 'barker')

Person merged = (p1.properties.findAll { k, v -> v }  // p1's non-null properties
               + p2.properties.findAll { k, v -> v }) // plus p2's non-null properties
               .findAll { k, v -> k != 'class' }      // excluding the 'class' property

assert merged.first == 'bob'
assert merged.last == 'barker'
assert merged.middle == null
```

Answer (score 4):

Just tested using reflection. The desired output is

```
merged person:Person{name=John, lastName=Snow}     



public static void testReflection() {
        Person p1 = new Person("John", null);
        Person p2 = new Person(null, "Snow");
        Person merged = (Person) mergePersons(p1, p2);
        System.out.println("merged person:" + merged);
}

public static Object mergePersons(Object obj1, Object obj2) throws Exception {
    Field[] allFields = obj1.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : allFields) {
        if (Modifier.isPublic(field.getModifiers()) && field.isAccessible() && field.get(obj1) == null && field.get(obj2) != null) {
            field.set(obj1, field.get(obj2));
        }
    }
    return obj1;
}
```

`mergePersons` accepts two Objects.

Then it go through all fields and validate if the first object has a null value. 
If yes, then it verify if the second object is not nulled.

If this is true it assigns the value to the first Object.

Providing this solution you only access public data. If you want to access private data aswell, you need to remove the Modifier verification and set if accessible before like:

```
public static Object mergePersons(Object obj1, Object obj2) throws Exception {
    Field[] allFields = obj1.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : allFields) {

        if (!field.isAccessible() && Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers())) 
            field.setAccessible(true);
        if (field.get(obj1) == null && field.get(obj2) != null) {
            field.set(obj1, field.get(obj2));
        }
    }
    return obj1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Given Groovy fields are implemented as a getter/setter pair with a backing field you can probably do it this way in Groovy:

```
static <T> void merge(T from, T to) {
    from.metaClass.properties.findAll { p ->
        p.getProperty(to) == null &&
            p.getProperty(from) != null &&
            to.respondsTo(MetaProperty.getSetterName(p.name))
    }
    .each {
        p -> p.setProperty(to, p.getProperty(from))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to go the reflection route. I'm assuming you have a default constructor, otherwise the following won't work. Also, it needs two same types.

```
public static <T> T mergeObjects(T first, T second) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        Class<?> clazz = first.getClass();
        Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
        Object returnValue = clazz.newInstance();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object value1 = field.get(first);
            Object value2 = field.get(second);
            Object value = (value1 != null) ? value1 : value2;
            field.set(returnValue, value);
        }
        return (T) returnValue;
    }
```

Here is example

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
public class Merge2Obj {

    private String name;
    private String lasName;

    public Merge2Obj() {
        super();
    }

    public Merge2Obj(String name, String lasName) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.lasName = lasName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLasName() {
        return lasName;
    }

    public void setLasName(String lasName) {
        this.lasName = lasName;
    }

    public static <T> T mergeObjects(T first, T second) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        Class<?> clazz = first.getClass();
        Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
        Object returnValue = clazz.newInstance();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object value1 = field.get(first);
            Object value2 = field.get(second);
            Object value = (value1 != null) ? value1 : value2;
            field.set(returnValue, value);
        }
        return (T) returnValue;
    }

     public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        Merge2Obj obj1 = new Merge2Obj("ABC", null);
        Merge2Obj obj2 = new Merge2Obj("PQR", "LMN");

        Merge2Obj obj3 = mergeObjects(obj1, obj2);

        System.out.println(obj3.name);
        System.out.println(obj3.lasName);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a mutable data class with getters and setters, Apache BeanUtils may suit your needs.

By default `BeanUtilBeansBean.copyProperties(Object dest, Object orig)` looks for pairs of `T orig.get*()` and `dest.set*(T value)`, and calls the latter with the result of the former.

But you can inject a custom `PropertyUtilsBean`, so you could wrap the default one to prevent it from replacing non-null properties:

```
public NoClobberPropertyUtilsBean extends PropertyUtilsBean {
     @Override
     public void setSimpleProperty((Object bean,
                          String name,
                          Object value)
                   throws IllegalAccessException,
                          InvocationTargetException,
                          NoSuchMethodException {
          if(getProperty(bean,name) == null) {
              super.setSimpleProperty(bean,name,value);
          }
     }
}
```

Now you can merge with:

```
BeanUtilsBean beanUtils = new BeanUtilsBean(new ConvertUtilsBean(), new NoClobberPropertyUtilsBean());
Person merged = new Person();
beanUtils.copyProperties(person1);
beanUtils.copyProperties(person2);
```

If a property is non-null in both sources, the first `copyProperties` wins.

You could of course change the semantics, for example it would behave a different way if the guard was `if(value != null)`.

At one level BeanUtils is just a wrapper around the kind of Reflection operations other answers suggest. It's up to you whether you want the extra level of abstraction. You may need to override more methods if you want to support map/list members, or BeanUtils' `DynaBean` class.